# Display field in ListBox

Tags: .net, vb.net

Very happy to join you ..
Please Gentelman .. 
How to display with same code in Listbox1 the field Localite From table Departement ..
Thank you in advance.
Cordially.
ABIDINE

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Database_Connection()
    InfoCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY Prenom", Con)
    InfoAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
    InfoAdapter.SelectCommand = InfoCommand
    InfoTable = New DataTable()
    InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = InfoTable


    ' ListBox1.DataSource = InfoTable   
    'From Departement where Localite 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new set of command, adapter and datatable. You can use the same connection. The adapter opens and closes the connection for you.The .DisplayMember is the name of the field you want visible in the ListBox. The ValueMembe can be set to the same field but it is offen convenient to set it to the primary key of the table.

```
        Dim DepCom As New SqlCommand("Select * From Departments", con)
        Dim DepAdap As New SqlDataAdapter(DepCom)
        Dim DepDT As New DataTable
        DepAdap.Fill(DepDT)
        ListBox1.DataSource = DepDT
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "DepartmentName"
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "DepartmentID"
```

Comment: Thank you Mary.Now it work perfectly.Thank you a lot.Cordially.ABE

Comment: Glad it helped. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this Code ...

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 Database_Connection()
 InfoCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY Prenom", Con)
 InfoAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
 InfoAdapter.SelectCommand = InfoCommand
 InfoTable = New DataTable()
 InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
 ListBox1.Items.Add(InfoTable)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Prakash

Comment: But i have a DatagridView1 and ListBox1 ..Datagrid will be filled by one Table ( Customers ) and listbox by another Table (Departement ).Thank you